# How can I change "edit" button to back button in UITableView in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, xcode7

I have a table that has an option to add cells.  In Simulator, instead of the default back button it says "edit".  I've got it set up to be able to swipe to delete, so I don't need this edit button.  How do I get this to go back to the default back button?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        meals.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

        saveMeals()

        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I fixed this by making my own back button with an action and adding a show segue in the interface builder.

```
@IBAction func back(sender: AnyObject) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Do not put a screenshot of your code. Copy/Paste it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack overflow, please take a tour here : [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Remove edit button from tab bar and select this tableview controller in storyboard . XCODE->EDITOR->Embed in ->NaviationControll. you will get default back buton.

Answer (score 0):

In your table view controller's `viewDidLoad()`, tell its navigation item to hide the left button, like `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil`.

Comment: I believe the OP wants the back button, will this show the back button?